# php page failing - ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() timeout error?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Running a heavy script, getting this error in apache log:

```
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed, referer: http://domains/scriptName.php
```

Tried upping max_execution_time, max_input_time to no avail. Is there some other setting I need to bump up?

It says timeout which makes me think it's not getting enough time to finish, but the "content_length_filter" is telling me maybe it's choking on too much data that the query is doing?

Comment: what distribution were you running this on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just running the script from command line